# Symbolic integration of 2D function with respect to one variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

```
syms x thetar;

moda1 =

((3387504564544983*cos(2*x))/140737488355328 - (5517699128844821*cos(6*x))/1125899906842624 + 20)*((25000*cos(44*thetar - 8*x))/19 - (50000*cos(36*x))/19 - (12630318182663471875*cos(44*thetar - 44*x))/5348024557502464 + (25000*cos(44*thetar - 80*x))/19 + 12630318182663471875/5348024557502464);

int(moda1,x,0,2*pi)

ans =

(63151590913317359375*pi)/668503069687808
```

In this I think `ans` should be a function of `thetar` but the answer is single valued.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct. It's simply a coincidence how you chose your interval that `thetar` disappears. Try other intervals and it's a function.